# github based php symfony deployment?

Tags: php, deployment, git

Does anyone know of a Heroku-like service for PHP (read: Symfony 1.4, PHP 5.3+) where I can use git(hub) to manage deployment?

Comment: By service you mean like hosting service? Or software that you run on your own servers?

Comment: Yeah, hosted - I could set up git and create scripts locally, but I want scalability built in.

Answer (score 4):

[PHPFog](http://phpfog.com)

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has PHP support. Check [this article](http://blog.pajap.com/?p=102) on how to run php frameworks on heroku